# Inserting an AnnotatedString into an EditText (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android-edittext, android-jetpack-compose, debouncing

I'm trying to solve the following issue. For example, I'm writing this text - "Hello *world*". After I stop writing, for example, after a second, the word "*world*" should be replaced by "world" in bold.
I've tried to do this, but so far it doesn't work.

```
    val originalText = MutableStateFlow("")
    val resultText = originalText
        .debounce(1000)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest { text ->
            val result = formatText(text) // create AnnotatedString
            flow { emit(result) }
        }
```

And trying to insert to EditText:

```
val resultText by viewModel.resultText.collectAsState(AnnotatedString(""))


OutlinedTextField(
     value = TextFieldValue(resultText),
     onValueChange = {
        viewModel.originalText.value = it.text
     },
     label = { Text("Description") },
     modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxHeight()
         .fillMaxWidth()
)
```

The problem is that I can't achieve the following result: we write text to "EditText" and after a second it is formatted and inserted into the same "EditText".
Could someone tell me, please, how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution, but I'm sorry for code. It's definitely worth improving.

ViewModel methods:

```kotlin
private var _wordList = mutableListOf<String>()
val wordList = _wordList

// Remove words that are not in the string
fun updateWordList(text: String) {
    _wordList.forEach {
        if(!text.contains(it)) {
            _wordList.remove(it)
        }
    }
}

fun getWords(text: String) : List<String> {
    val regex = Regex("\\*(.*?)[\\*]")
    val matches = regex.findAll(text)
    return matches.map { it.groupValues[1] }.toList()
}

fun addWords(text: String) {
    val words = getWords(text)
    words.forEach { word ->
        if(!_wordList.contains(word)) _wordList.add(word)
    }
}
```

A method which create an AnnotatedString:

```kotlin
fun getAnnotatedString(text: String, words: List<String>): AnnotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    append(text)

    words.forEach { word ->
        if (text.contains(word)) {
            val offsetStart = text.indexOf(word)
            val offsetEnd = offsetStart + word.length

            addStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                start = offsetStart,
                end = offsetEnd
            )
        }
    }
}
```

After that we need to create the following variables:

```kotlin
val words = viewModel.getWords(description)
viewModel.addWords(description)

val descResult = if (words.isEmpty()) description else description.replace("*", "")
val formattedString = formatString(descResult, viewModel.wordList)

var textFieldValueState by remember {
   mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(annotatedString = formattedString))
}
val textFieldValue = textFieldValueState.copy(annotatedString = formattedString)
```

And finally, we define the OutlinedTextField:

```kotlin
OutlinedTextField(
    value = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = {
        viewModel.updateWordList(it.text)

        if (tmp == it.text) {
            textFieldValueState = it
            return@OutlinedTextField
        }
        description = it.text
        textFieldValueState = it
    },
    label = { Text("Description") }
)
```